# Perl: Use backreferences in a replacement string variable

Tags: regex, perl

I am performing a string substitution in Perl, but I have both the pattern and the replacement strings stored as scalar variables outside the regular expression operators. The problem is that I want the replacement string to be able to use backreferences.

I hope the code below will illustrate the matter more clearly.

```
my $pattern = 'I have a pet (\w+).';
my $replacement = 'My pet $1 is a good boy.';
my $original_string = 'I have a pet dog.';

# Not Working
my $new_string = $original_string =~ s/$pattern/$replacement/r;

# Working
#my $new_string = $original_string =~ s/$pattern/My pet $1 is a good boy./r;

# Expected: "My pet dog is a good boy."
# Actual: "My pet $1 is a good boy."
print "$new_string\n";
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```perl
s/$pattern/My pet $1 is a good boy./
```

is short for

```
s/$pattern/ "My pet $1 is a good boy." /e
```

The replacement expression (`"My pet $1 is a good boy."`) is a string literal that interpolates `$1`.

---

This means that

```perl
s/$pattern/$replacement/
```

is short for

```perl
s/$pattern/ "$replacement" /e
```

The replacement expression (`"$replacement"`) is a string literal that interpolates `$replacement` (not `$1`).

---

While it may be hindering you, it's a good thing that `perl` isn't in the habit of executing the contents of variables as Perl code. :)

You can use `gsub_copy` from [String::Substitution](https://metacpan.org/pod/String::Substitution) to solve your problem.

```perl
use String::Subtitution qw( gsub_copy );

my $pattern         = 'I have a pet (\w+)\.';
my $replacement     = 'My pet $1 is a good boy.';
my $original_string = 'I have a pet dog.';

my $new_string = gsub_copy($original_string, $pattern, $replacement);
```

Answer (score 4):

That `$1` in the replacement string is just successive chars `$` and `1`, and to make it into a *variable* for the first capture you'd have to go through bad hoops.<sup>†</sup>

How about an alternative

```
my string = q(a pet dog);

my $pattern = qr/a pet (\w+)/;

my $new = $string =~ s/$pattern/ repl($1) /er;


sub repl {
    my ($capture) = @_;
    return "$capture is a good boy";
}
```

where the sub is really just

```
sub repl { "$_[0] is a good boy" }
```

It's a little more but then it's more capable and flexible.

---

<sup>†</sup> Or, as it turns out per ikegami's answer, use [String::Substitution](https://metacpan.org/release/String-Substitution/source/lib/String/Substitution.pm) which wraps up  into a single call all needed 'niceties' so to avoid doing bad things (string `eval` that is)

Comment: The problem, actually, is that I will be parsing strings from a file. This file would be a list of patterns + replacements. This a good working solution, but I may not be able to use it for this task unfortunately.

Comment: @kedarguru  So you have `pet $1 is good` in the file, with an actual `$1`?  Or  else?

Comment: @kedarguru Can you show a pattern+replacement from the file? (In dog-words is fine :)

Comment: Sure. For my specific task, the pattern and replacement strings will not have white space (though a general solution will be good). Each line will represent a pattern+replacement pair, which will be separated by some character (let's say a comma in this example). So we can say the file is like (complete nonsense here):
animals_(\w+)\d+, mypet$1
(grape|jack|kiwi)fruit_(\w+), $2\.color
...
The file type and contents I can be flexible about. It's just that no matter how I parse it, I think I will be reading in strings, hence running into the problem.

Comment: ^Sorry I don't know how to format text in the comments. But each "<pattern>, <replacement>" is a new line.

Comment: @kedarguru, Re "*I don't know how to format text in the comments.*", You can't create multi-line comments. If you need to clarify the question, it can be edited.

Comment: @kedarguru  Alright, I see.  Now you've got ikegami's answer for exactly what you envisioned so that's all good.  Otherwise I'd probably suggest to consider a different set up for that info.